# Numpy Python - Create 1d vector - value of zero if index in a list, else value of 1/300

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vector, conditional-statements

I'm trying to create a numpy vector (x0) with a given length (6436 entries). Each item in this vector corresponds to an airport.

I have another data frame that shows the airports that are currently active with outbound flights. segments["ORIGIN_INDEX"] is the data frame that contains all airports with outbound flights, with 300 airports in this list.

My goal is to create this vector (x0), where there is some sort of condition. If the airport index corresponds to an airport with outbound flights, then the value would be 1/300 ; otherwise, the value would be zero.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
 x0 = []

 for i in len(flights_array):
     if flights_array[i] is not #outbound_flight:
           x0[i] = 1/300
     else:
           x0[i] = 0
```